# aurelia bindable object property not serialized in json

Tags: json, post, serialization, aurelia

so like in title i have a problem with serialization of composition object.

Class "Resort" has two bindalbe properties: Address and Manager.  both are not serialized by httpClient.json but if remove @bindable - serialization work perfect. Where is problem ?

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Address} from './../models/address.js'
import {Employee} from './../models/employee.js'

export class Resort {
    id = "";
    name="";
    category_id = "";
    organization_id = "";
    manager_id = "";
    owner_id = "";
    active = "";
    deleted = "";
    date_created = "";
    date_modified = "";
    checkin = "";
    checkout = "";
    date_deleted = "";
    notes = "";
    address_id = "";

    @bindable address = new Address();
    @bindable manager = new Employee();

    category_attraction = [];
    category_option = [];
}
```

this is my fetching code:

```
this.http.fetch('resorts', {
            method: 'post',
            body: json(resortObject)
        })
```

RESULT of json function:

```
{"id":"","name":"LOLO","category_id":"","organization_id":"","manager_id":"","owner_id":"","active":"","deleted":"","date_created":"","date_modified":"","checkin":"","checkout":"","date_deleted":"","notes":"","address_id":"","category_attraction":[],"category_option":[]}
```

TIA :)

Comment: As far as I know, @bindable properties should be used in web component classes. In my opinion, if your class is a web component you shouldn't post it to your server, you should convert it to a plain javascript object instead. Imagine if your class has some properties and functions, which are necessary for handling states and events. You wouldn't want to send all these unnecessary information to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because those attributes have been wrapped as property getter/setter and are no longer enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know why you have that behaviour, but you could try to use `JSON.serialize(resortObject)` instead of `json(resortObject)`